# Old Equnox (Eclipse) project for Java8 failed to rebuild itself after a recent update

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tycho

There is an old Java8 OSGI project. The maven build started to fail after the recent (Aug 2022) update of the **org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.formattedtext** to the version **1.0.0.202208171905**.

The older version **1.0.0.202205212120** was OK.

The updated one produces the error:

```
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: com.company.product 1.2.3.qualifier
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.formattedtext 1.0.0.202208171905 requires 'osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))' but it could not be found
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: com.company.product 1.2.3.qualifier depends on: osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.formattedtext 1.0.0
[ERROR]
[ERROR] See http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Dependency_Resolution_Troubleshooting for help.
[ERROR] Cannot resolve dependencies of MavenProject: com.company.product:com.company.product:1.2.3-SNAPSHOT @ C:\dev\designer\com.company.product\pom.xml: See log for details -> [Help 1]
```

What should be changed to make it work again?
Thank you

P.S. The POM file is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XIe6dkujNygpsvZ-KY6puqMUOTHrKsPa/view

Comment: In your `pom.xml`, does adding `<resolveWithExecutionEnvironmentConstraints>false</resolveWithExecutionEnvironmentConstraints>` to your target platform configuration fix it (for details see https://www.eclipse.org/justj/?page=documentation)? Otherwise, show your `pom.xml`.

Comment: Yes, I tried the above switch. Did not help.

The main pom is here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XIe6dkujNygpsvZ-KY6puqMUOTHrKsPa/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Eclipse Mars and Tycho 1.2.0, are you kidding? Tycho 1.2.0 is probably too old to understand `resolveWithExecutionEnvironmentConstraints`. Please improve your question by including the content of your `pom.xml`.

Comment: That version of the formattedtext appears to require Java 11, it probably isn't going to run with just Java 8.

Comment: Yes, I know about EOL versions. Unfortunately, we cannot go from Mars. Regarding Tycho, is there any good version to move to?

And for the version of FormattedText. Can we specify the old version to pull?

Comment: I updated Tycho to 2.3.0 and it resolved. 

Please create an answer so I can approve. Thank you all very much.